# fill form fields from database via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to fill form fields from database via ajax jquery.
I use Codeigniter.
i can retrieve and alert database values to an array as this image.
[alert of the data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmsBm.png)
my problem is how to access this php array values via javascript?
i want to fill form fields from this array using js.
appreciate help :)

here is my Javascript

```
 $("#header3").on("click", ".edit_button", function(e) {
        var site_path = $('#sitePath').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedID = this.id.split('_'); //Split ID string
        var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
        var myData = DbNumberID; //build a post data structure
        //getting data for the form from accuse table
        $.ajax({
            url:site_path +'/queries/get_data_form3',
            method:'POST',
            data:{myData:myData},

            success:function(data12)
            {
             alert(data12);
            }
            ,
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });
```

here my controller code

```
 public function get_data_form3(){
        $insert_id =  $this->input->post('myData');
        $this->load->model('queries1');
         if( $posts_form3=  $this-> queries1 ->getPostsFor_form3i($insert_id) ) {
               print_r($posts_form3);
         }else{
             echo "failed";
         }
    }
```

Comment: return the data like this  echo json_encode($posts_form3);

Comment: You probably want to `echo json_encode($posts_form3);` in the php side, the use `var getJson = JSON.parse(data12);` on the javascript side.

Comment: i tried this and it returns an array. but when i access field names it says "undefined". i tried every column always says undefined. here is js lines   var getJson = JSON.parse(data12);
                alert(getJson.name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the data like this on server side instead of print_r($posts_form3);

```
 echo json_encode($posts_form3);
```

Access the data in client side like this

```
 success:function(data12)
        {
         var datas = JSON.parse(data12);

          console.log(datas[0]['name']);
        }
```

Access the data like this

```
  datas[0]['name']; datas[0]['address']; datas[0]['sex'];
```

Comment: i tried this and it returns an array. but when i access field names it says "undefined". i tried every column always says undefined. here is js lines var getJson = JSON.parse(data12); alert(getJson.name);

Comment: your accessing wrong use like this alert(getJson[0].name); try this @tharaka

Comment: glad to help you @tharaka

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `print_r($posts_form3);` use:

```
echo json_encode($posts_form3);
```

from the `get_data_form3(){` function and receive it in ajax like:

```
success:function(data12)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(data12);
}
```

You can access all the element in data like:

`data[0].column` or `data[0][column]`

Comment: i tried this and it returns an array. but when i access field names it says "undefined". i tried every column always says undefined. here is js lines var getJson = JSON.parse(data12); alert(getJson.name);

Comment: Its an 2d kind of array, so please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data in JSON format for get data in ajax. Please replace you code with below code.

```
$("#header3").on("click", ".edit_button", function(e) {
        var site_path = $('#sitePath').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedID = this.id.split('_'); //Split ID string
        var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
        var myData = DbNumberID; //build a post data structure
        //getting data for the form from accuse table
        $.ajax({
            url:site_path +'/queries/get_data_form3',
            method:'POST',
            data:{myData:myData},

            success:function(data12)
            {
             var getData = JSON.parse(data12);
             console.log(getData);
            }
            ,
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });
```

And below php code.

```
public function get_data_form3(){
        $insert_id =  $this->input->post('myData');
        $this->load->model('queries1');
         if( $posts_form3=  $this-> queries1 ->getPostsFor_form3i($insert_id) ) {
               echo json_encode($posts_form3);
         }else{
             echo "failed";
         }
    }
```